# Create PDF iOS7

Tags: pdf-generation, ios7

to create a pdf programmaticallly inside my iOS app I followed this tutorial on mobile.tut+:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/generating-pdf-documents/

but two methods are now deprecated in iOS7, but what xcode suggest to use instead of old methods doesn't seems to work. somebody have an idea?

thanks!

```
    - (CGRect)addText:(NSString*)text withFrame:(CGRect)frame fontSize:(float)fontSize{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:fontSize];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;

    NSDictionary*attributi = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph};

    NSStringDrawingContext* drawCont = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc]init];
    drawCont.minimumScaleFactor = 0.0;


    //IOS6 deprecated method

//  CGSize stringSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(_pageSize.width - 2*20-2*20, _pageSize.height - 2*20 - 2*20) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

//IOS7 method suggested by xcode

    CGRect stringSIZ = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(_pageSize.width - 2*20-2*20, _pageSize.height - 2*20 - 2*20) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributi context:drawCont];

    float textWidth = frame.size.width;

    if (textWidth < stringSIZ.size.width)
        textWidth = stringSIZ.size.width;
    if (textWidth > _pageSize.width)
        textWidth = _pageSize.width - frame.origin.x;

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, textWidth, stringSIZ.size.height);

         //IOS6 deprecated method
//    [text drawInRect:renderingRect
//            withFont:font
//       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
//           alignment:NSTextAlignmentNatural];

    //IOS7 method suggested by xcode
    [text drawInRect:renderingRect withAttributes:attributi];

    frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, textWidth, stringSIZ.size.height);

    return frame;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I create my own class to create pdf as easy as possible in iOS7. if somebody need it, here it is:

PDFHelper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PDF : NSObject{
}
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGSize size;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *headerRect;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *header;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imageArray;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imageRectArray;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *textArray;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *textRectArray;

@property(nonatomic, strong)  NSMutableData *data;

+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
// i metodi vanno invocati nel seguente ordine:
-(void)initContent;
-(void)addImageWithRect:(UIImage*)image inRect:(CGRect)rect;
-(void)addTextWithRect:(NSString*)text inRect:(CGRect)rect;
-(void)addHeadertWithRect:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect;

- (void) drawText;
- (void) drawHeader;
- (void) drawImage;
- (NSMutableData*) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath;
@end
```

PDFHelper.m

```
#import "PDF.h"

@implementation PDF
@synthesize size, imageArray, header, imageRectArray, textArray, textRectArray, data, headerRect;
-(void)initContent{
    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    imageRectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    textArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    textRectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    header = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    headerRect = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    data = [NSMutableData data];
  //  data = [NSMutableData data];

}
- (void) drawHeader
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [header count]; i++) {


        CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        NSString *textToDraw = [header objectAtIndex:i];


        NSLog(@"Text to draw: %@", textToDraw);
        CGRect renderingRect = [[headerRect objectAtIndex:i]CGRectValue];
        NSLog(@"x of rect is %f",  renderingRect.origin.x);


        UIFont*font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:30.0];

        UIColor*color = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:79/255.0 blue:79/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        NSDictionary*att = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color};
        NSStringDrawingContext *context = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
        context.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1;
        //        [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withAttributes:att];
        [textToDraw drawWithRect:renderingRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:att context:context];
    }

}
-(void)drawImage{
    for (int i = 0; i < [imageArray count]; i++) {
        [[imageArray objectAtIndex:i] drawInRect:[[imageRectArray objectAtIndex:i]CGRectValue]];

    }
}
- (void) drawText
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [textArray count]; i++) {


    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    NSString *textToDraw = [textArray objectAtIndex:i];


        NSLog(@"Text to draw: %@", textToDraw);
        CGRect renderingRect = [[textRectArray objectAtIndex:i]CGRectValue];
        NSLog(@"x of rect is %f",  renderingRect.origin.x);


        UIFont*font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:22.0];

        UIColor*color = [UIColor blackColor];
        NSDictionary*att = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color};


        [textToDraw drawWithRect:renderingRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:att context:nil];
}

}
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
-(void)addImageWithRect:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect{
    UIImage *newImage = [PDF imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];


    [imageArray addObject:newImage];
    [imageRectArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]];
}
-(void)addTextWithRect:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [textArray addObject:text];
    [textRectArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]];
}
-(void)addHeadertWithRect:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [header addObject:text];
    [headerRect addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]];
}

- (NSMutableData*) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);


    BOOL done = NO;
    do 
    {
        //Start a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), nil);

        //Draw Header
        [self drawHeader];
        //Draw Text
        [self drawText];
        //Draw an image
        [self drawImage];

        done = YES;
    } 
    while (!done);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();


    //For data    
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRectZero, nil);


    BOOL done1 = NO;
    do 
    {
        //Start a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), nil);

        //Draw Header
        [self drawHeader];
        //Draw Text
        [self drawText];
        //Draw an image
        [self drawImage];

        done1 = YES;
    } 
    while (!done1);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return data;
}
```

Now import the PDf.h in the class and use something like this to create and draw your pdf:

```
-(void)CreaPDFconPath:(NSString*)pdfFilePath{


    UIFont*font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:22.0];

    UIColor*color = [UIColor blackColor];
    NSDictionary*att = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color};

    NSString* text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n\n%@", self.ingredienti.text, self.preparazione.text];

    CGFloat stringSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(980, CGFLOAT_MAX)// use CGFLOAT_MAX to dinamically calculate the height of a string
                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                         attributes:att context:nil].size.height;

    //creo pdf e vi aggiungo testo e immagini
    PDF*pdfFile = [[PDF alloc]init];
    [pdfFile initContent];
    [pdfFile setSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 400+stringSize)];

    [pdfFile addHeadertWithRect:self.fieldNome.text inRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 980, 60)];

    [pdfFile addImageWithRect:self.image.image inRect:CGRectMake(10, 80, 250, 250)];

    NSString*stringInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@ \n\n%@",self.oreCottura.text,self.minutiDiCottura.text,self.numeroPersone.text];
    [pdfFile addHeadertWithRect:stringInfo inRect:CGRectMake(300, 190, 500, 120)];

    [pdfFile addTextWithRect:text inRect:CGRectMake(10, 350, 980, CGFLOAT_MAX)];


    //disegno header immagine e testo
    [pdfFile drawHeader];
    [pdfFile drawImage];
    [pdfFile drawText];
    //genero pdf
    [pdfFile generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFilePath];
}
```

Comment: Looks like a handy class, but I don't know why you called it a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the PDF Generation issues from recent deprecated methods since IOS7 release:

```
- (void)drawDate
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(160, 120, [[self date]frame].size.width, self.date.frame.size.height);
    NSString *dateString = self.date.text;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphstyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphstyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraphstyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    NSDictionary * attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName:font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphstyle };
    [dateString drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

Hope this helps.  LMK if you have comments...

Answer (score 0):

You can this code working. Please try!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PDFHelper : NSObject{
}
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGSize size;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *headerRect;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *header;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imageArray;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imageRectArray;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *textArray;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *textRectArray;

@property(nonatomic, strong)  NSMutableData *data;

+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
// i metodi vanno invocati nel seguente ordine:
-(void)initContent;
-(void)addImageWithRect:(UIImage*)image inRect:(CGRect)rect;
-(void)addTextWithRect:(NSString*)text inRect:(CGRect)rect;
-(void)addHeadertWithRect:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect;

- (void) drawText;
- (void) drawHeader;
- (void) drawImage;
- (NSMutableData*) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath;
@end
```

>

```
#import "PDFHelper.h"
@implementation PDFHelper
@synthesize size, imageArray, header, imageRectArray, textArray, textRectArray, data, headerRect;
-(void)initContent{
    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    imageRectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    textArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    textRectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    header = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    headerRect = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    data = [NSMutableData data];
    //  data = [NSMutableData data];

}
- (void) drawHeader
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [header count]; i++) {


        CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        NSString *textToDraw = [header objectAtIndex:i];


        NSLog(@"Text to draw: %@", textToDraw);
        CGRect renderingRect = [[headerRect objectAtIndex:i]CGRectValue];
        NSLog(@"x of rect is %f",  renderingRect.origin.x);


        UIFont*font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:30.0];

        UIColor*color = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:79/255.0 blue:79/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        NSDictionary*att = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color};
        NSStringDrawingContext *context = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
        context.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1;
        //        [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withAttributes:att];
        [textToDraw drawWithRect:renderingRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:att context:context];
    }

}
-(void)drawImage{
    for (int i = 0; i < [imageArray count]; i++) {
        [[imageArray objectAtIndex:i] drawInRect:[[imageRectArray objectAtIndex:i]CGRectValue]];

    }
}
- (void) drawText
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [textArray count]; i++) {


        CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        NSString *textToDraw = [textArray objectAtIndex:i];


        NSLog(@"Text to draw: %@", textToDraw);
        CGRect renderingRect = [[textRectArray objectAtIndex:i]CGRectValue];
        NSLog(@"x of rect is %f",  renderingRect.origin.x);


        UIFont*font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:22.0];

        UIColor*color = [UIColor blackColor];
        NSDictionary*att = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color};


        [textToDraw drawWithRect:renderingRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:att context:nil];
    }

}
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
-(void)addImageWithRect:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect{
    UIImage *newImage = [PDFHelper imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];


    [imageArray addObject:newImage];
    [imageRectArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]];
}
-(void)addTextWithRect:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [textArray addObject:text];
    [textRectArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]];
}
-(void)addHeadertWithRect:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [header addObject:text];
    [headerRect addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]];
}

- (NSMutableData*) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);


    BOOL done = NO;
    do
    {
        //Start a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), nil);

        //Draw Header
        [self drawHeader];
        //Draw Text
        [self drawText];
        //Draw an image
        [self drawImage];

        done = YES;
    }
    while (!done);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();


    //For data
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRectZero, nil);


    BOOL done1 = NO;
    do
    {
        //Start a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), nil);

        //Draw Header
        [self drawHeader];
        //Draw Text
        [self drawText];
        //Draw an image
        [self drawImage];

        done1 = YES;
    } 
    while (!done1);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return data;
}
@end
```

>

```
-(void)CreaPDFconPath:(NSString*)pdfFilePath{

    NSArray *arrayPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                        NSDocumentDirectory,
                                        NSUserDomainMask,
                                        YES);
    NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* imagePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    UIFont*font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:22.0];

    UIColor*color = [UIColor blackColor];
    NSDictionary*att = @{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color};

    NSString* text = @"Test1";

    CGFloat stringSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(980, CGFLOAT_MAX)// use CGFLOAT_MAX to dinamically calculate the height of a string
                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                         attributes:att context:nil].size.height;

    //creo pdf e vi aggiungo testo e immagini
    PDFHelper*pdfFile = [[PDFHelper alloc]init];
    [pdfFile initContent];
    [pdfFile setSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 400+stringSize)];

    [pdfFile addHeadertWithRect:@"Field Text" inRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 980, 60)];

    [pdfFile addImageWithRect:image inRect:CGRectMake(10, 80, 250, 250)];

    NSString*stringInfo = @"Info";
    [pdfFile addHeadertWithRect:stringInfo inRect:CGRectMake(300, 190, 500, 120)];

    [pdfFile addTextWithRect:text inRect:CGRectMake(10, 350, 980, CGFLOAT_MAX)];


    //disegno header immagine e testo
    [pdfFile drawHeader];
    [pdfFile drawImage];
    [pdfFile drawText];
    //genero pdf
    [pdfFile generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFilePath];
}
```