# Use of undeclared identifier Xcode

Tags: xcode, pdf

I always turn to stack overflow in order to clarify programming issues. I found a question which deals with creating PDF files in x code that I am trying to implement. The post can be found here [Create PDF iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942144/create-pdf-ios7) My problem begins at the very las instruction for the completed answer (The one with the green check) that reads "Now import the PDf.h in the class and use something like this to create and draw your pdf:" I do not understand what the instructions mean when they say "Import the PDF.h class" Where would I import this?

I am providing the link to that questions so it is easier for anyone to find it.

thanks in advance!!

Link to question: [Create PDF iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942144/create-pdf-ios7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the two files that were written in the answer you linked (PDFHelper.h and PDFHelper.m). Then in the class that needs to create a PDF add: `#import "PDFHelper.h"`

After doing this, you can access the PDFHelper class and its functions.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dehli,

I created those files under NSObject just like the linked example. I would like to display the pdf in my ViewController. The ViewCOntroller is a class, correct? I Can then import "PDFHelper.h" to the View Controller header file?

Comment: Yup! That's exactly where you'd want to import it.

Comment: Great! One last question. After I import the "PDFHelper.h" inside the viewcontrller.m file, That last chunk of code goes inside the view controller.m as well?

Comment: I got an error saying "Use of Undeclared Identifier 'CreaPDFconPath' " . I added the chunk of code inside my viewDidLoad inside my viewController.m file and imported the "PDFHelper.h" inside my view controller.m file. But I receive that error message. Is there something I am doing wrong? (Obviously) Thanks for all your help

Comment: You shouldn't put that in viewDidLoad. It's supposed to be its own function.

Comment: I managed to get it to work. Thank you so much. I am marking this question as complete. Thanks a lot Dehli!